# Printing to a specific printer / changing default printer

Tags: printing

I have multiple printers for different media formats / sizes connected to a single Windows 7 machine running *Mathematica* 11.0.1.0. I'd like to be able to direct `NotebookPrint` output to a particular printer programmatically depending on the desired format.

Upon starting *Mathematica*, the system default printer is the one used for `NotebookPrint` commands. Changing the system default printer outside of *Mathematica* during a kernel session doesn't seem to change the printer used for `NotebookPrint`. It's possible to select a particular printer using the `File -> Print...` dialog, and that selection seems to persist for the remainder of the kernel session or until a different selection is made.

Is there a syntax (aside from `Interactive -> True`) to specify which printer should be used for a `NotebookPrint` operation?